# how to refer to the text value?

Tags: php

```
$list_box_contents = array();

  $list_box_contents[0] = array('params' => 'class="productListing-odd"');
  $list_box_contents[0][] = array('params' => 'class="productListing-data"',
                                              'text' => TEXT_NO_PRODUCTS);
```

i want to make a condition whether there is a value in `$list_box_contents[0][]["text"]` .when i write the code `if(!empty($list_box_contents[0][]["text"]))`. my IDE alet me there is an error. what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[] it's **not** a position, index or something like this.

With

```
$list_box_contents[0][] = array('params' => 'class="productListing-data"',
                                              'text' => TEXT_NO_PRODUCTS);
```

you are pushing the array with its two value (and keys) on the right of the `=` in the last position of the subarray which has index 0.  That is the structure you'll have is:

```
$list_box_contents[0] => array(VALUES-BEFORE, [last-position-key] => array('params' => 'class="productListing-data"', 'text' => TEXT_NO_PRODUCTS))
```

Anyway to have an idea of what happens, you can use `print_r($list_box_contents)` or `var_dump($list_box_contents)`

after the lines you posted.

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["params"]=>
    string(26) "class="productListing-odd""
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["params"]=>
      string(27) "class="productListing-data""
      ["text"]=>
      string(47) "There are no products to list in this category."
    }
  }
} this is the print_r($list_box_contents)  when i echo $list_box_contents[0][0]["text"]; why i can't get the text value?

Comment: @runeveryday Because $list_box_contents[0][0] it's an exact position while $list_box_contents[0][] not.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign something as in `$list_box_contents[0][]`, you are assigning the contents of whatever follows to the next element in the array `$list_box_contents[0]`.  So in this case, you would be assigning

`array('params' => 'class="productListing-data"',
                                              'text' => TEXT_NO_PRODUCTS);`

to index 0 of `$list_box_contents[0]`.

You can't refer to it using the `$array[]` notation, because the PHP parser doesn't have any idea which element in `$array` that you want to refer to.  You need to specify.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["params"]=> string(26) "class="productListing-odd"" [0]=> array(2) { ["params"]=> string(27) "class="productListing-data"" ["text"]=> string(47) "There are no products to list in this category." } } } this is the print_r($list_box_contents) when i echo $list_box_contents[0][0]["text"]; why i can't get the text value?

Comment: If that is what `print_r` is reporting, I see no reason why you would not be able to output the value of `$list_box_contents[0][0]["text"]`.